# Should I syncronize an access to a memory with HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | HOST_COHERENT_BIT flags?

Tags: vulkan

In other words is it possible that the GPU will read the memory while I mapping it on the host and writing to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a distinction between "visibility" and "availability" in Vulkan's memory model. You need *both* if you want to access a value.

Coherency is about "visibility". But you still need availability. `HOST_COHERENT` says that you don't need `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` or `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges`. For CPU writes, visibility requires `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` (which `HOST_COHERENT` effecitvely provides), but that alone is insufficient for availability:

> `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` guarantees that host writes to the memory ranges described by `pMemoryRanges` **can** be made available to device access, via availability operations from the `VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT` access type.

The "availability operations" section links to the Vulkan section on "Execution and Memory Dependencies". So even with coherent mapping, you still need to have a dependency between the host writing that memory and the GPU operation reading it.

For GPU reading operations from CPU-written data, a call to `vkQueueSubmit` acts as a host memory dependency on any CPU writes to GPU-accessible memory, so long as those writes were made *prior* to the function call.

If you need more fine-grained write dependency (you want the GPU to be able to execute some stuff in a batch while you're writing data, for example), or if you need to read data written by the GPU, you need an explicit dependency.

For in-batch GPU reading, this could be handled by an event; the host sets the event after writing the memory, and the command buffer operation that reads the memory first issues `vkCmdWaitEvents` for that event. And you'll need to set the appropriate memory barriers and source/destination stages.

For CPU reading of GPU-written data, this could be an event, a timeline semaphore, or a fence.

But overall, CPU writes to GPU-accessible memory still need some form of synchronization.

Comment: I am a bit confused about this. Isn't the next `vkQueueSubmit` call makes available all coherent or non-coherent but flushed memory written by the host? The spec. says: *"When batches of command buffers are submitted to a queue via vkQueueSubmit, it defines a memory dependency with prior host operations, and execution of command buffers submitted to the queue."* Then why is the `vkCmdWaitEvents`? Also, if it is truly  required, then staging buffers should be synchronized before they are being copied to their device local destination buffers via `vkCmdCopyBuffer` as well. Am I wrong?

Comment: @plasmacel: I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but according to my mental model (any combination of coherent/non-coherent/cached) host accesses must make sure that the buffer is currently not used by the GPU, by good ol' unsynchronized ring-buffer style multi-buffering, or using fences/timeline-semaphores, or by a newly created buffer.

Comment: @plasmacel: That's out of scope for the question as asked.

Answer (score 2):

Coherent memory just means that you don't need to manually manage the CPU caches with `vkInvalidateMappedMemoryRanges` and `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges`. You still need to use synchronization to make sure that reads and writes from CPU and GPU happen in the right order, and you need memory barriers on the GPU side to manage GPU caches (make CPU writes visible to GPU reads, and make GPU writes available to CPU reads).

Comment: Thank you. But can you please elaborate more on "you need memory barriers on the GPU side to manage GPU caches". When do I need them? As I understand, if I write on host only and read on gpu, I need only fences.

Comment: @nikitablack When GPU reads data from a memory, it caches it to have a much quicker access to that data. And even though coherent memory is automatically updated without the need to flush it, cache may not be synchronized. For that You need to set an image or buffer memory barrier via the vkCmdPipelineBarrier() function. It also works the other way, to store rendering results in a memory. As for the fences - they are set by the GPU but only CPU may read them. For CPU to GPU synchronization You need events.

Comment: @nikitablack: "*As I understand, if I write on host only and read on gpu, I need only fences.*" Fences only synchronize operations from the GPU to the CPU. I think you're talking about Events. And yes, an Event could work; the GPU reading operation waits on the Event and the CPU operation signals it. But `vkCmdWaitEvents` is effectively a barrier; it is provided the usual memory synchronization stuff (source/destination stage, memory barriers, etc).